# Animate a View to a selected cell in collectionView or tableView in scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, scrollview

I know the title is not explanatory, but the following image will explain what I want to achieve.

[image]

Is there any way that I can complete this task?

Comment: Do you want to add that view inside the tableview/ collectionview

Comment: Is "didSelect a Cell" an element? Because it looks like one in your drawing, though it sounds like an action.

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal No I don't want to add, I want to move a view to exactly to a selected cell.

Comment: @IulianOnofreiI just want to show I did select a cell

Comment: @AshleyMills I don't want to add a view, I want to move a view already exist :)

Comment: @AshleyMills I need animated move, my friend. Then I'll make the view full screen. If I just add a view into a cell, there will be no fancy animations :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is…

- Find a common superview to both your view and cell
- Calculate the start position in the superview
- Calculate the end position in the superview relative to the cell
- add the view to the superview at the start position
- Animate to the end position
- add the view to the cell, keeping it in position

You'll need to use

```
convert(_rect:, to view:) -> CGRect
```

to find `A view`'s start and end position in the common superview